# Carry convergence from one series to another

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have

*(i)* $\alpha_n \geq 0$,  $\beta_n \geq 0$ such that

*(ii)* $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \beta_n = 1$, and

*(iii)* $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\alpha_n < \infty$. Intuitively, if

*(iv)* $\forall N \in \mathbb{N} :\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n \leq \sum_{n=1}^N \beta_n$

then I should also get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\beta_n < \infty$.

(Sorry, there was a typo in the original equation *(iv)*: the direction of the inequality was reversed). Here is my proposed solution, but I feel queasy about some steps so please point out any mistakes.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \alpha_n 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \sum_{m=n}^\infty  \alpha_n 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left(1 - \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}  \alpha_n \right) $

$\geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left(1 - \sum_{m=1}^{n-1}  \beta_n \right)  
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \sum_{m=n}^\infty  \beta_n 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \beta_n $

Comment: actually I have a solution, but I don't know if it is correct; I will edit to post to add it, so if anyone could point out correctness or mistakes, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Your outline is fine.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thanks. I would like to better understand the basic concepts to follow when manipulating series, in order to be more comfortable in the future -- is there a textbook which you would recommend?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo : actually, looking back at this, I have trouble justifying the first step: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \alpha_n 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \sum_{m=n}^\infty  \alpha_n$.

Comment: I guess that should be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \alpha_n 
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \sum_{m=n}^\infty  \alpha_m$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, there are some typos in the subindices, just as you indicate (some $n$s should be $m$s).